# jqGrid loading aspx webservice using mtype post json not loading grid

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, jqgrid

I have been struggling with getting this to work for a number of days now.

oddly , I have gotten it to sort of work through various trials - but now its not loading at all

here is my setup:

```
$("#table-Select").jqGrid({
                        url: 'SelectionListService.asmx/GetList',
                        mtype: 'POST',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }, 
                        postData: { SelectionType:  'Project' },
                        colNames: ['id', 'Title', 'DocumentID'],
                        colModel: [
                                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20,hidden: false },
                                    { name: 'Title', index: 'Title' ,width: 220,hidden:false},
                                    { name: 'DocumentID', index: 'DocumentID',width: 220, hidden: false}
                                    ],
                        hidegird: false,
                        autowidth: true,
                        //height: 'auto',
                        rowNum: 0,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                        pager: jQuery('#table-SelectPager'),
                        sortname: 'Title',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        loadonce: true,
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        caption: "Select Project",
                        //fixes Invalid JSON Primitive error
                        serializeGridData: function (postData) { 
                                if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null; 
                                if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null; 
                                if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null; 
                                //if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null; 
                                return JSON.stringify(postData);
                            }, 
                         jsonReader: {
                            root: "rows",
                            page: "page",
                            total: "total",
                            records: "records"
                            }

                        }).navGrid('#table-SelectPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

Here is the JSON data coming from the WebService call :

```
{"d":{"__type":"NCR.SelectionListService+JQGrid","page":1,"total":4,"records":4,"rows":[{"id":"1","DocumentID":"pgmprj://aecomme/newdohaportproject/envcomp","Title":"NDPP-Environmental Compliance Monitoring"},{"id":"2","DocumentID":"pgmprj://aecomme/newdohaportproject/ndpp-portbasinandinnerbreakwatersconstruction","Title":"NDPP-Port Basin and Inner Breakwaters Construction"},{"id":"3","DocumentID":"pgmprj://aecomme/newdohaportproject/ndpp-programmanagement","Title":"NDPP-Program Management"},{"id":"4","DocumentID":"pgmprj://aecomme/newdohaportproject/ndpp-supplementarysiteinvestigation","Title":"NDPP-Supplementary Site Investigation"}]}}
```

I know it must be something simple i am missing - but after all of the examples I have looked at - I have no idea what I am missing.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the `jsonReader` option to the following:

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "d.rows",
    page: "d.page",
    total: "d.total",
    records: "d.records",
    repeatitems: false
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Nutshell.htm).

Comment: Thanks Oleg for that - I was just about to hit on that one and you beat me too it - thanks again.  The odd thing is , wheni click the Sort functions - all of my rows go away - even though all of the records are still there according to $("#table-Select").jqGrid('getGridParam', "records");

Comment: ***UPDATE***, found the issue on sorting, for some reason i had seen in someones example rowNum: 0  , so i tried setting this on mine, it loads the first set find, but then doing so causes the Sorting to clear out the records on the grid.  Love the jqGrid - thanks Oleg!